# Architecting a C# console app for multiple different tasks

Tags: design-patterns, c#-4.0, console-application

I want to build a simple C# console app that can be run from the command-line and that will do   different tasks.What is the best way to architect this flexibly? I can see how the various tasks could be built with the Strategy pattern. Is the Main() function just a giant switch? How do people typically implement this general concept?

UPDATE: I am looking "stylistically" at git/hg or like, but maybe less actions. A user would work at the command-line, issuing a task with associated params, ex: `git add -f`. So, using that as an example, Git/Mercurial allow extensions. I'm actually looking for various general ways to approach this issue, and benefits/tradeoffs of approaches. No one design is perfect.

Comment: Without writing a complete detailed answer, you would use a command line arguments to drive different logic paths. If there still isn't a decent answer to this by tomorrow, I will push one up. I've done a lot of this type of work before and have some rather neat solutions.

Comment: Are you using any sort of dependency injection framework? If you were you could use it to pull up all the "Task" implementations in main() and provide a simple menu from them to let the user choose.

Comment: @Mike: I haven't started anything. It's a blank slate at the moment, design-wise. I am familiar with DI/IoC. Just wondering if that's the only way... Thx.

Comment: @exacerbatedexpert: There's always someone on SO who gets offended (or exacerbated) way too easily. I'm looking for guidance and design ideas from peers. Excuse me for knowing patterns or mentioning IoC. And, I read the Patterns book years ago. Be careful of what they say about "assume". BTW, once you get past your anger at patterns, you'll realize they are just lingo to speed discussion between devs.

Comment: @exacerbatedexpert: What kind of detail do you want in addition to looking at git's behavior at the command-line as an example? What am I missing in my question? I'm honestly baffled that we can't start discussing options.

Comment: I think your question is fine and I look forward to posting a reply later when I've got some more time.

Comment: So, what's a good site for architectural questions, since it seems like people here (like Peter Ritchie or CasperOne) are trigger happy on arbitrarily and randomly closing questions on design-related guidance?

Comment: Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062661/building-c-sharp-console-app-for-multiple-instances?rq=1

Comment: I don't think this question should have been closed. The objective is clear "from a high level how to I architect a .Net console application for flexibility", I don't believe this is outside of the SO scope. Additionally there are several people interested in providing detailed answers (to what is a good question) and no suggestions were made by either Casper One or Peter Ritchie as to why this question was closed. This is on-topic and a real question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: FYI my approach is to use `CommandLine` tool suggested by @akton with required attributes for the tool and a series of booleans describing the commands the console app can handle. I use MEF as an IoC container to bring in all classes that inherit from my command abstract base class which has a `RunAnalysis()` method and `Validate(args)` method. I loop through each command and run them if the arguments pass validation.

Comment: [continued] I also have console print helpers squirreled away with helpers like `PrintTitle(string)`, `GetPassword()`, `ShowPercentComplete()` and `UpdatePercentComplete(float)` so all actions write in a consistent format to the console.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have complex command line arguments, first use a command line parsing library like http://commandline.codeplex.com/. Then use the [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) and for the different actions and create a model (or classes that control the system). For example, if you have an "add" command, create a "AddCommand" class that calls the appropriate methods and properties on the model.

Comment: Thanks for that. Never heard of that library, but will be a good "ingredient" to consider.